# When to use Binomial Heap?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

`Binomial Heap` has quite special design. Personally I don't think this design is intuitive.

Although posts such as [What is the difference between binary heaps and binomial heaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215485/what-is-the-difference-between-binary-heaps-and-binomial-heaps) talks about diff and its speciality, I am still wondering when I should use it.

In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap, it says

> Because of its unique structure, a binomial tree of order k can be
>   constructed from two trees of order k−1 trivially by attaching one of
>   them as the leftmost child of root of the other one. This feature is
>   central to the merge operation of a binomial heap, which is its major
>   advantage over other conventional heaps.

I presumes that an advantage of Binomial Heap is its merge. However, `Leftist heap` also has O(logN) merge and much simpler, why we still use Binomial Heap? When should I use Binomial Heap?

---

**edit**

One of the actual question I wanna ask here is **What's exactly the advantage of Binomial Heap**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article for the [Leftist tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree) says:

> When inserting a new node into a tree, a new one-node tree is created and merged into the existing tree. To delete a minimum item, we remove the root and the left and right sub-trees are then merged. Both these operations take O(log n) time. For insertions, this is slower than binomial heaps which support insertion in amortized constant time, O(1) and O(log n) worst-case.

So it appears that the advantage of Binomial heap is that insertions are faster.

At least, that's what asympotitic analysis tells us. Real world running time is something else entirely and, as Gene said in his answer, depends on constant factors. The only way you can determine which is better for your application is to test them.

Comment: Downvoter? Something you want to share? It's customary to provide a reason for the downvote.

Comment: Yes! Many problems discard the heap, so insert times are more important.  A binomial heap may be the fastest sort on a modern system because of locality of reference.  It is not a stable sort unless enhanced to secondarily key on insert order.  It does not need a size like the array based Priority Queue.  It does not discard sort effort like a FIbonacci Heap, which is just a corruption of the binomial heap.  I posted more detail on enhancements and code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504823/has-anyone-actually-implemented-a-fibonacci-heap-efficiently/77834698#77834698

Answer (score 6):

Binomial heaps support the merge operation (destructively merge two heaps) in logarithmic time, whereas it takes linear time with a binary heap.

Comment: linear time or nlogn in binary heap?

Comment: @JacksonTale- That operation takes O(n) time in a binary heap because you can use the heapify operation to build a new heap from the two existing heaps in linear time.

Comment: You are referring to the *meld*.  Yes, O(log N) of the *smaller* heap, like to meld a 1-K heap into a 1M heap, as the 1-K heap has 10 root trees to add to the 1M heap root tree list.  If you have a tail pointer for root, you can splice the lists together O(1), but in some heaps you need to merge any matching rank trees.  It is "destructive" in the sense that the new tree has pointers to nodes in the old tree, and most tree operations modify nodes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no general answer to your question.

The constant factor in the run time relation to data size for library-level algorithms like this often governs which to choose. For example if an O(1) operation is a factor of 20 times slower than an O(log n) one when n=1, you're better off choosing the O(log n) algorithm for n < 1,000,000.

The conclusion is that asymptotic time bounds are only a guide.  You'd use Binomial rather than Leftist heaps if

1. The difference matters in the application.  (If it doesn't use the cheapest reliable implementation at hand regardless of algorithm.)
2. BH benchmarks better than LH in the particular application you're building.

**Added**
In response to the OP's comment that he is looking for motivation: I can't speak for this algorithm's author. But in general, algorithm developers live to find novel, beautiful approaches and publish them even if the advantage they provide is marginal or purely theoretical.

This is good. It's how Computer Science progresses.  The *approach* can pay off big in other settings even if there is no big win on the problem at hand.

An (old) example of this is skip lists that were developed in 1989 to solve the same problem with very near the same efficiency as balanced binary search trees, which were known in 1962 or earlier.  Why bother?  Because we can.

Comment: What's exactly the advantage of Binomial Heap?

Comment: @JacksonTale as I said, there is no general answer. When you benchmark it, it might perform better than other algorithms due to constant factors of execution of certain ops. My guess is that its merge operation will have less overhead than the LH merge. But you must benchmark it to find out. Complex does not mean slow.

Comment: I guess the answer OP's asking is more directed towards, "What motivated someone to design Binomial Heap?". Because he said the design is "not intuitive", so he must be wondering why it was constructed in the first place, and he thought that there must be a particular use for it.

Comment: @justhalf yes. I just wish for a motivation.

Comment: @JacksonTale See addition to answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Binary Heap < Binomial Heap < Fibonacci Heap

This is only with respect to performance. 
From Wiki,

```
+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| Operation  |    Binary     | Binomial | Fibonacci |
+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| Find-min   | Θ(1)          | Θ(1)     | Θ(1)      |
| delete-min | Θ(log n)      | Θ(log n) | O(log n)  |
| insert     | Θ(log n)      | Θ(1)     | Θ(1)      |
| dec-key    | Θ(log n)      | Θ(log n) | Θ(1)      |
| merge      | Θ(m log(n+m)) | O(log n) | Θ(1)      |
+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized, simplified binomial heap is not much more complex than any other.  The node has a generic or templated value, one byte rank, and two pointers or references: next and child, both forward linked lists using next.  This is identical in structure to an AVL tree or heap!  The basic class has just a root pointer/reference to the root tree forward linked list, a little forest.  You add nodes to the root list but merge equal rank nodes together into a rank+1 node, possibly repeatedly, but on average less than one merge per insert.  On merge, the loser goes on the child list of the winner, to be ignored until the winner is deleted as the min/max.

I optimized by deferring any concern about the min/max until a peek or pop of min.  This speeds the insert.  When you peek min, it merges all the trees on the root list, increasing rank of lower rank nodes to match any next rank.  This narrows the root for future peek/pop min/max.  My root list is sorted unique ascending on rank so if a rank 0 insert collides with a rank 0 root tree, they merge into a rank 1 tree but may collide with a root rank 1 tree.  The root normally (until you fake out the rank to merge all trees) has one tree for every bit is the heap size, like a rank 0 and 2 tree for size 5.

While not a stable sort, the binomial heap may be the fastest sort on a modern system due to great locality of reference.  You can make it stable with a hidden secondary key of insert sequence.